# Why does coercing a column in a data.table with by not work while coercing without does work without warning?

Tags: r, data.table

Below I am doing the same operation in two ways. The first does not work, while the second does work. I am wondering why? I have not been able to find an answer to this question in data.table documentation or other places through google.

```
SOtable <- data.table(testInt=c(1:100))
SOtable[,testInt := as.double(testInt), by=1:nrow(SOtable)]
##Error in `[.data.table`(SOtable, , `:=`(testInt, as.double(testInt)),  : 
## Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
SOtable[,testInt := as.double(testInt)]
```

The reason to try this is because I wanted to do some manipulation on a column in a big data.table for each row, but as soon as I use `by` I get the LHS/RHS error. But as I am typing this I am thinking: "Maybe I should have used some `apply` function for this instead?"

Comment: In your first example: Let's say for the first group you turn `testInt` into a double variable. In the second group you expect it to be an integer variable, which you want to turn into a double. That means the same variable is expected to have two modes. That's not possible. data.table doesn't actually `split` the data for `by` operations.

Comment: Aaah @Roland, so when I do it with `by` it tries to write each seperate answer into the data.table one by one (writing a double while the rest are still ints) and it does not create a whole new column first with which to replace the old column. That makes sense!

Comment: @Gullydwarf `:=` works by reference, i.e., it modifies in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @Roland:

In the first example you replace an entire column so the variable type is not a factor.
When using `by` each value gets written into the column when calculated so if the types differ it will try to write (in this case) a double variable into a integer column, which is not going to work.